# accessing variable list coordinates with an if statement

Tags: python, list, if-statement, tkinter

For this python 2.7 tkinter code, if I enter 'Apple' and hit the 'Search' button, I should reset the string variable options and associated radiobuttons from unknown ("?") to those describing apples ("Crunchy") and ("Temperate") but I'm having trouble accessing list of lists coordinates with my if statement.

```
from Tkinter import*

class Fruit:
    def __init__(self, parent):

    # variables
    self.texture_option = StringVar()
    self.climate_option = StringVar()

    # layout
    self.myParent = parent

    self.main_frame = Frame(parent, background="light blue")
    self.main_frame.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

    texture_options = ["Soft", "Crunchy","?"]
    climate_options = ["Temperate", "Tropical","?"]

    self.texture_option.set("?")
    self.climate_option.set("?")

    self.texture_options_frame = Frame(self.main_frame, borderwidth=3, background="light blue")
    self.texture_options_frame.pack(side=TOP, expand=YES, anchor=W)
    Label(self.texture_options_frame, text="Texture:", relief=FLAT, font="bold", background="light blue").pack(side=LEFT,anchor=W)
    for option in texture_options:
        button = Radiobutton(self.texture_options_frame, text=str(option), indicatoron=0,
        value=option, padx=5, variable=self.texture_option, background="light blue")
        button.pack(side=LEFT)

    self.climate_options_frame = Frame(self.main_frame, borderwidth=3, background="light blue")
    self.climate_options_frame.pack(side=TOP, expand=YES, anchor=W)
    Label(self.climate_options_frame, text="Climate:", relief=FLAT, font="bold", background="light blue").pack(side=LEFT,anchor=W)
    for option in climate_options:
        button = Radiobutton(self.climate_options_frame, text=str(option), indicatoron=0,
        value=option, padx=5, variable=self.climate_option, background="light blue")
        button.pack(side=LEFT)

    #search button
    self.search_frame = Frame(self.main_frame, borderwidth=5, height=50, background="light blue")
    self.search_frame.pack(expand=NO)

    self.enter = Entry(self.search_frame, width=30)
    self.enter.pack(side=LEFT, expand=NO, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)

    self.searchbutton = Button(self.search_frame, text="Search", foreground="white", background="blue",
    width=6, padx="2m", pady="1m")
    self.searchbutton.pack(side=LEFT, pady=5)
    self.searchbutton.bind("<Button-1>", self.searchbuttonclick)
    self.searchbutton.bind("<Return>", self.searchbuttonclick)


def searchbuttonclick(self,event):
    #fruit  texture  climate 
    fruit_bowl=[
    ('Apple', 'Crunchy','Temperate'),
    ('Orange', 'Soft','Tropical'),
    ('Pawpaw','Soft','Temperate')]

    if self.enter.get()==fruit_bowl[i][0]:
        self.texture_option.set(fruit_bowl[i][1])
        self.climate_option.set(fruit_bowl[i][2])


root = Tk()
root.title("Fruit Bowl")
fruit = Fruit(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I want to say if the entry window equals column 0 for any given row in fruit_bowl then the texture option sets to the column 1 value for that row and the climate option sets to the column 2 value for that row, but how do I say that in python?

I had originally ommitted the gui components of this code to simplify things, but apparently just made everything more complicated and made my code look choppy and odd.  The code above should give you a nice GUI window, but hitting the search button does nothing but generate the following error message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python25\Lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1403, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "F:\Python\fruit.py", line 59, in searchbuttonclick
if self.enter.get()==fruit_bowl[i][0]:
NameError: global name 'i' is not defined
```

Is there a list comprehension or something I could use to settle this instead of rewriting my code?  This is a mock example to try and settle issues I'm having with a much larger  module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  example-code is not very consistent. For example you define an `StingVar` object, which would make sense if you would couple the object with an tkinter widget like the `Entry` widget:

```
self.entry_var = StringVar()
self.enter = Entry(root, width = 30, textvariable = self.entry_var)
selection = self.entry_var.get()
```

considering that, i would ommit your head-part and do it like:

```
self.enter = Entry(root, width=30)
self.enter.pack(side=LEFT, expand=NO)

#fruit  texture  climate 
fruit_bowl={'apple': ('Crunchy','Temperate'),
            'orange': ('Soft','Tropical'),
            'pawpaw': ('Soft','Temperate')}

selection = self.enter.get()
try:
   self.texture_option = fruit_bowl[selection.lower()][0]
   self.climate_option = fruit_bowl[selection.lower()][1]
   self.fruit_option = selection.capitalize()
except KeyError:
    print "%s not in fruit-bowl" % selection
```

If you want to keep your code as it is you would have to make something like the following:

```
for fruit in fruit_bowl:
    i = fruit_bowl.index(fruit)
    if self.enter.get()==fruit_bowl[i][0]:
        self.texture_option.set(fruit_bowl[i][1])
        self.climate_option.set(fruit_bowl[i][2])
```

Where did you define the variable `i`? I can't see a definition and so can't python either.
To correct the situation i made an iteration over your `fruit_bowl` and assigned the value
of the actual tuple-index in the list to the variable `i.
That are the only two lines you would have to add (except the added identations of the following lines) to make your code work. It's not ver elegant, but maybe you can learn something out of it.

alternativly you could also consider doint this:

```
for i in xrange(len(fruit_bowl)):
    if self.enter.get()==fruit_bowl[i][0]:
        self.texture_option.set(fruit_bowl[i][1])
        self.climate_option.set(fruit_bowl[i][2])
```

If you have further question, just post a comment and i will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: It looks odd because it's a snippet of a larger code linking the string variables to radiobuttons.  Will post whole thing.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll settle for functional if inelegant for now.  As my skills improve, no doubt the code will get less klunky.

Answer (score 4):

You should use a dictionary for that:

```
fruits = {'Apple': ['Crunchy', 'Temperate'],
          'Orange': ['Soft', 'Tropical'],
          'Pawpaw': ['Soft', 'Temperate']}
print 'Apples are {}.'.format(' and '.join(fruits['Apple']))
```

Edit: See also the [standard library documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) and the [official tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Edit #2: Of course you can also set the variables like that:

```
self.texture_option.set(fruits['Apple'][0])
self.climate_option.set(fruits['Apple'][1])
```

You can also write something like that:

```
fruit = self.enter.get()
self.texture_option.set(fruits.get(fruit, ['?', '?'])[0])
self.climate_option.set(fruits.get(fruit, ['?', '?'])[0])
```

Where `['?', '?']` is used as option, if the fruit is not known by your program.

Comment: Thank you for showing me an alternate way to code my tuple as a dictionary, but printing the 'Apples' statement does not equate to setting the string variable options.  I'm also still curious how to express variable tuple coordinates

Comment: I thought your (only) problem was accessing the 'texture' and 'climate' option.  Hm, ok.  You could access the characteristics of the 'Apple' with a tuple too: `list(filter(lambda x: x[0] == 'Apple', fruits))`, but that would be not as nice as using dictionaries.